# HTML5 : Google IMA show default progress bar and countdown

Tags: google-ima

Anyone know how to configure adsRenderingSettings  so that the default progressBar and countdown timer are shown during ad playback ? If I inspect the iframe during ad playback I notice that the divs w/ **videoAdUiProgressBar** and **videoAdUiBottomBar** are both set to display:none .

The google docs  don't have too much:  https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/v3/apis?hl=uk#ima.UiElements.COUNTDOWN

---

Here is a snippet I've tried

```
.....
    var adsRenderingSettings = new google.ima.AdsRenderingSettings();
    adsRenderingSettings.uiElements = ['UiElements.COUNTDOWN','UiElements.AD_ATTRIBUTION'];

    adsManager = adsManagerLoadedEvent.getAdsManager(videoContent,adsRenderingSettings);
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, the "learn more" button on top right corner show in mobile browsers only, does not show in desktop browsers,
Is there any way to make the button show in all browsers?

Answer (score -1):

Try following

```
var adsRenderingSettings = new google.ima.AdsRenderingSettings();
adsRenderingSettings.uiElements = [google.ima.UiElements.COUNTDOWN, google.ima.UiElements.AD_ATTRIBUTION];

adsManager = adsManagerLoadedEvent.getAdsManager(videoContent,adsRenderingSettings);
```

This does show Countdown. For progress bar, i'm also looking for an answer.

Comment: It's not an answer but a suggestion. Comment the question instead when you'll acquire the privilege to comment.